# Role of root accidentally changed to read only

Tags: vmware-esxi

Could someone please advise how I can get role of root back to administrator - please note we have no other admin role other than vpxuser and dcui. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Try the following: Log on as root via the ESXi Shell at the console, or via ssh if ssh is enabled. Then edit the file /etc/vmware/hostd/authorization.xml. Find the line "<ACEDataUser>root</ACEDataUser>". The line above should be "<ACEDataRoleId>-2</ACEDataRoleId>". Change -2 to -1 and save the file.